# 500 Internal Server Error The request was not completed. The server met an unexpected condition. for php files

Tags: php, opencart

I am using a linux(dailyrazor) server and when i uploaded the php files, it throws an error like
"500 Internal Server Error
The request was not completed. The server met an unexpected condition." but when i am uploaded html files it works fine. The error message changes to

```
403 Forbidden  Access is forbidden to the requested page:
```

Can you suggest where the problem is?

Comment: Look in the `error.log` file of your web server

Comment: Its definitely going to be a htaccess problem

Answer (score 0):

check you have upload files with different ftp username and password... you have only modify access